# Explicitly calling base class constructor in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

May I ask if we are allowed to explicitly call base class constructor in derived class? (if not, why?)

I'm asking this question because I wrote the following toy code and the results confuse me:

```cpp
class X
{
public:
    void wow()
    {
        cout << "wow\n";
    }
protected:
    X()
    {
        cout << "creating X\n";
    }
    X(int i)
    {
        cout << "creating X with i\n";
    }
};

class Y : protected X
{
public:
    X r = X{ 1 };  // error at this line: (C2248) 'X::X': cannot access protected member declared in class 'X'
};

int main()
{
    Y y;
    y.r.wow();
}
```

However, if I make a slight modification in `class Y`, the code actually compiles:

```cpp
// X defined same as above...

class Y : protected X
{
public:
    X r = { 1 };
};

int main()
{
    Y y;        // creating X
                // creating X with i
    y.r.wow();  // wow
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Note that class Y has 2 `X`, the base class, and as member.

Comment: The design seems off. Is `Y` an `X`? Or should it just contain an `X`?

Comment: Also, when asking questions about build errors then please always include the actual errors you get.

Comment: "the results confuse me" means whatever error your receiving has a rightful place being verbatim-replicated [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72139942/edit), preferably with your understanding, if any, of what is possibly indicates

Comment: Inheritance doesn’t give full access with `protected`, you have access to protected field only through the derived class. So you cannot access protected field for your member.

Comment: Neither of these compile with clang or gcc (where clang gives the helpful note of "protected constructor can only be used to construct a base class subobject"). Probably a visual studio bug

Comment: @Artyer Could you please explain a little bit more on such behaviors of constructors? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance doesn’t give full access with `protected`, you have access to protected field only through the derived class. So you cannot access protected field for your member. In more detail see

[Protected_member_access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access#Protected_member_access)

> A protected member of a class is only accessible
>
> [..]
>
> 2. to the members and friends (until C++17) of any derived class of that class, but only when the class of the object through which the protected member is accessed is that derived class or a derived class of that derived class:

Second sample should fail also for same reason (And actually do for clang/gcc [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vdYjYvWz9)). I would say msvc bug.

Comment: this is only half the answer. In the second variant of the code `X r = { 1 };` compiles

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: only for msvc (I suspect a bug).